# Scala Futures: How to guarantee a non-null result?

Tags: java, scala, asynchronous, concurrency, completable-future

Let's say I have a method that returns `CompleteableFuture[Data]`:

```
def doIt(): CompleteableFuture[Data] = { ... }
```

And, there's a non-zero chance that `doIt()` can return `null`. How can we call `doIt()` until the result isn't `null` without blocking the calling thread? What's the approach in Scala?

My current attempt:

```
Future {
  var data: Data = null
  blocking {
    while (data == null) { data = doIt().get }
  }
  data
}
```

I'd prefer not to use `blocking` and `get`. Any ideas?

Also, there're `map` calls on this Future after the fact:

```
val myFuture = Future {
  var data: Data = null
  blocking {
    while (data == null) { data = doIt().get }
  }
  data
}.map { d => d.someMember }
```

`d.someMember` will throw a `NullPointerException` unless we ensure the first `Future` has a non-null result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat:

```
import scala.compat.java8.FutureConverters._

def doItNotNull: Future[Data] = 
  doIt.toScala.flatMap {result =>
    if (result == null) doItNotNull // try again
    else Future.successful(result) // wrap in a completed future
  }
```